# Excel ADODB Query Dates for year 2021

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to Query Excel Column for Dates ( for example this is 2021, then only retrieve 2021 dates from column)
This is what I have

```
    CurrMonth = Format$(Date, "m/d/yyyy")
    PrevMonth = Format$(Date - Day(Date), "m/d/yyyy")
    sSQL = "SELECT * " & _
           "FROM [TEST2$] AS M  " & _
           "WHERE M.[something] = '" & rs.Fields("something").Value & "' AND " & _
           "      M.[Date] BETWEEN #" & PrevMonth & "# and #" & CurrMonth & "#" & _
```

Comment: What output do you get? Or what error message?

Comment: Also looks like there is code missing from the bottom of your example

Comment: As in `"' AND Year(M.[Date]) = " & Year(Date)`?

Comment: am still getting records from 2020@d0little

Comment: Try changing the date format to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Use an `ADODB.Command` with actual `Parameter` objects, assign actual `Date` values to the parameter values, replace the string concatenations with `?` parameters (get rid of all the delimiters), and you won't have to worry about date formats anymore. The SQL command string should look like `"SELECT m.* FROM [TEST2$] m WHERE m.[Something]=? AND m.[Date] BETWEEN ? AND ?;"`

Comment: "      M.[Date] BETWEEN #" & sStartDate & "# AND  #" & sEndDate & "# " & _

Answer (score 1):

When you send a query to a database server with ADODB, you should **never** have to deal with string concatenations and string and date literal delimiters.

Instead, use a properly parameterized `Command` and send a *constant* command string to the server:

```vb
'SQL string is a compile-time constant that NEVER includes any kind of user inputs:
Const sql As String = "SELECT m.* FROM [TEST2$] m WHERE m.[Something]=? AND m.[Date] BETWEEN ? AND ?;"

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = yourAdodbConnectionInstance
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = sql

'now append the positional parameters in order; use an actual Date value (not a String) for an adDate parameter:
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(...)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(...)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(...)

'now invoke .Execute and retrieve the results recordset:
Dim results As ADODB.Recordset
Set results = cmd.Execute
```